# SVN: How to create diff of branch to trunk, for code review?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a merging problem:

I created a branch by copying the trunk, creating rev 1000. Then I added a
new file `blah.txt` to the branch. Now I want to merge this (and
other) changes back to my checkout of the trunk:

```
cd ~/trunk-checkout
svn merge -r 1000:2000 $REPOS/branches/foo
A  blah.txt
```

That creates my new file `blah.txt` in the trunk checkout. But when I
say:

```
svn diff blah.txt
```

the output is empty. Shouldn't the output be the whole file, since it
doesn't yet exist in the trunk?

How can I get the `svn-diff` to the trunk, which would contain the
whole new file `blah.txt`?

Even when I say this (in the directory where the new file `blah.txt` is):

```
svn diff -r HEAD  $REPOS/trunk/foo
```

it is empty.

The background of my question is: I need to submit a diff of my code (which is on the branch) to the trunk for code review (see [here](http://www.reviewboard.org)). The diff should look like this:

```
$ svn diff blah.txt
Index: blah.txt
===================================================================
--- blah.txt    (revision 0)
+++ blah.txt    (revision 0)
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have copied branch from the trunk with `svn cp`, you should reintegrate it back with `svn merge --reintegrate`. You are merging without `--reintegrate` and with specific revisions range `-r ...` (why?).

So, generally the workflow should go like this:

```
svn cp ^/trunk/ ^/branch/foo

#In the foo branch working copy:
foo $ work, work, work...

#In the working copy of trunk:
trunk $ svn merge --reintegrate ^/branch/foo
```

Then running `svn diff` will show you all the changes you did in the branch:

```
trunk $ svn diff
... all the changes that were done in foo ...
```

---

There is another way to solve your problem. To get diff of all (or part of) the changes that were done in the specific branch you don't need to merge. Using `svn diff` is enough:

Determine which changes you want to see in the diff.
Use `svn log` to check FROM which and TO which revision the work was done:

```
svn log -v |less
```

If you want to determine in which revision you created a branch, do:

```
svn log -v --stop-on-copy | less
```

The last log entry will be the first revision of the branch.

Now execute `svn diff` with `-r` (range):

```
svn diff -r FROM-1:TO .
```

You can use `HEAD` keyword instead of revision number to indicate the last committed revision in the branch.

So to get a diff of all your branch work you will need to run:

```
svn diff -r FIRST_BRANCH_REV:HEAD
```

where `FIRST_BRANCH_REV` is the first revision of the branch.